# Mock object method by calling another object's method with the first one's arguments?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I just want to do this:

```
Mockito.when(methodOne.read(Mockito.any(byte[].class)).
thenReturn(methodTwo.read(***The argument methodOne was called with (aka whatever was Mockito.any(byte[].class))***));
```

Specifically, I have an inputstream that reads into a byte[] array. However, this inputstream cannot be read from during unit testing, so I need to mock this by reading from another inputstream that I will hardcode some values. This other input stream should also read into the byte[] array. Any way to do this?

I tried the below but it gives me a weird error message: error: incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that Answer conforms to byte[]:

```
Mockito.when(inStreamOne.read(Mockito.any(byte[].class))).then(inStreamTwo.read(returnsFirstArg()));
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just replace the stream with the fake for the test, instead of trying to mock it in such a complex way?

Comment: @Kayaman So the problem that I have is that the stream is a child class of InputStream which I've found very difficult to construct, and I cannot replace it with a generic InputStream

Answer (score 0):

**The problem**

You received error message:

```
no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that Answer<T> conforms to byte[]
```

The argument to method `then` (which is an alias for `thenAnswer`) must be of type `Answer<?>`

- `returnsFirstArg()` is an `Answer<T>` that looks at the invocation and returns the first argument (inferring the return type)
- you cannot pass `returnsFirstArg()` to `inStreamTwo.read()`.
  `Answer<T>` will never become `byte[]`, no matter what `T` is inferred.
  This is the meaning of the error message.

**Solution**

You must create your own instance of `Answer<Integer>`

- take the first argument (`byte[]`)
- call `read` on the underlying stream
- return the result of read

```
var buffer = new byte[4];
Mockito.when(inputStreamOne.read(Mockito.any(byte[].class)))
       .thenAnswer(invocation -> {
           byte[] buf = invocation.getArgument(0);
           return sourceInputStream.read(buf);
       });
```